# partial view form submits object bound to parent view model instead of its own model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-binding, partial-views

I have the following bits from my test application.

A method used for posting the data from a partial view.

```
public IActionResult AddPayor(Payor newPayor)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        mvSrv.SaveOnePayor(newPayor);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Payor");
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And index cshtml view where I want to have a list of item plus the ability to add more.
Notice the model class PayorView; it contains a list of payors to use in the ViewPayor view and a single payor to use in the AddPayor view. I do it this way so that the AddPayor can have an object passed down even when the list is empty. Earlier I tried to have only the list as the model but sending the [0] element failed when list was empty.

```
@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers"
@model FSA_Tracker.ViewModels.PayorView
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<partial name="ViewPayor" for="payors" />

<partial name="AddPayor" for="payor" />
```

The partial view for AddPayor is just an input form. The model object is pass down from the parent view.

```
@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers"
@model FSA_Tracker.Models.Payor

<fieldset>
    <form asp-action="AddPayor" method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="input-validation-error"></div>
        <div id="formContainer">
            <p>
                <label asp-for="Name"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name"></span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <button type="submit">Add Payor</button>
            </p>
        </div>
    </form>
</fieldset>
```

My problem is that the newPayor argument in my post method does not get initialized, but rather what gets initialized is the PayorView.payor property in the parent view model object. So I can make it work if I change to

and I extract the payor from there.

Is there a way to prevent my partial view from binding its object to the parent view model? Preferably from the parent view.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try passing in the payor model into your partial view like:

```
<partial name="ViewPayor" model="@Model.Payor" />
```

Comment: Nope. Still same issue. I changed to ```<partial name="AddPayor" for="@Model.payor" />``` and the partial view submit data is still bound to the parent view's object. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I needed to instantiate and pass the new new model into the partial. Now I see what Matthias L meant. I just didn't know I could go to a different namespace than the one in the declaration section. This will give the partial view a new Provider object rather than an attribute from the parent view.

```
@{
    var provider = new FSA_Tracker.Models.Provider();

    <partial name="AddProvider" model="@provider" />
}
```